# Android Studio Gradle Build Error: String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value '')

Tags: android, gradle

Just downloaded Android Studio. Followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/firebase-app-engine-android-studio) tutorial verbatim. Keep running into the following error when trying to "Build", and I do not know how to get past it.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
C:\Users\SV\AndroidStudioProjects\ToDoApp\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml
Error:(872, 69) String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value '').
Error:(872, 69) String types not allowed (at 'activity_horizontal_margin' with value '').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1.429 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: You're missing a value for the `<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">` in one of the files in your `res/values/` folders.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `values` folder create a file call it `dimens.xml` if you don't have one already. Then add the following code inside it:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>
</resources>
```